# How to implement for loop in objective c

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I am using Xcode 5 , I write this method but unfortunately this error appear: USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER otherCard. Although I declare it in the for loop:

```
- (void)chooseCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    card *card =[self cardAtIndex:index];
    if(card.isMatched){
        if(card.isChosen){
            card.chosen =NO;

        }else {
            for(card *otherCard in self.cards){
                if(otherCard.isChosen && !otherCard.isMatched){
                    int matchScore =[card match:@[otherCard]];
                    if(matchScore){
                        self.score +=matchScore;
                    } else {
                        self.score -= MISMATCH_PENALTY;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post some more details? At what line compiler is throwing an error.

Comment: tow lines 1. int matchScore =[card match:@[otherCard]] 2.if(otherCard.isChosen && !otherCard.isMatched)

Comment: Yes i Have declard it in  the card class

Comment: do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: Using a lower cased class name is poor. Using the same name as an instance name is poorer.

Comment: yes so as mentioned bellow the problem in this line card *card =[self cardAtIndex:index]; thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line may be throwing off the compiler:

```
card *card =[self cardAtIndex:index];
```

Is card the class type or the variable name? It can't be both.

Comment: yes that right, now it is working, thank you , so it is not allowed to declare instance with same class name

Comment: Correct. As others have added below, you want to stick to the convention of naming all classes with two or three capital letters. That makes it clear to you (and others who may read your code later), which is a class and which is a variable. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you defined variable `card` to be of class `card` earlier you hid the definition of class `card`.  (A good reason to use the standard naming convention where class names always start with an Upper Case character.)